# scrapy error : exceptions.IOError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting the following error many times without knowing the image file name or the response url to track it:

```
2012-08-20 08:14:34+0000 [spider] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 545, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 362, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 458, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 545, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py", line 204, in media_downloaded
    checksum = self.image_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py", line 252, in image_downloaded
    for key, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py", line 261, in get_images
    orig_image = Image.open(StringIO(response.body))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
exceptions.IOError: cannot identify image file
```

So, how could I solve this issue? cause it stops my spider after a specific number of errors that I already defined in settings.py

Comment: When does this error happen? Are you using something like PIL to work with images?

Comment: Post the entire stacktrace (error).

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah, such error usually happens when PIL wants to parse image that is only partially downloaded

Comment: @stav , I edited the post and added the entire stacktrace.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko, I guessed so, but how could I ignore this errors to prevent spider from stopping ??

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah, obviously you must wrap that piece of code into try-except

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko Would you tell me how? if you have some knowledge with scrapy. cause I think it's being done automatically. I can't even find where is it being called!

Comment: This sounds like a Scrapy issue.  I'd like to try and reproduce it locally: can you post your spider code, or at least the start_urls.

Comment: @stav Here's the spider code http://chopapp.com/#66pa226p

Answer (score 3):

The offending line uses PIL to `Image.open()` in scrapy.contrib.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline:

```
def get_images(self, response, request, info):
    key = self.image_key(request.url)
    orig_image = Image.open(StringIO(response.body))
```

The try block in media_downloaded() catches this but issues an error itself:

```
except Exception:
    log.err(spider=info.spider)
```

You could hack this file with:

```
try:
    key = self.image_key(request.url)
    checksum = self.image_downloaded(response, request, info)
except ImageException, ex:
    log.msg(str(ex), level=log.WARNING, spider=info.spider)
    raise
except IOError, ex:
    log.msg(str(ex), level=log.WARNING, spider=info.spider)
    raise ImageException
except Exception:
    log.err(spider=info.spider)
    raise ImageException
```

but the better option would be to create your own pipeline and override the image_downloaded() method in your pipelines.py file:

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline

class BkamImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def image_downloaded(self, response, request, info):
        try:
            super(BkamImagesPipeline, self).image_downloaded(response, request, info)
        except IOError, ex:
            log.msg(str(ex), level=log.WARNING, spider=info.spider)
```

Be sure to declare this pipeline in your settings file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'bkam.pipelines.BkamImagesPipeline',
]
```

Comment: but I'm usting their image resizing option and also uploading amazon s3. So, will using custom images pipeline stop the core pipeline functionalists (image resizing & amazon s3) ?

Comment: You can have as many pipelines as you want: `ITEM_PIPELINES = [ 'bkam.pipelines.BkamImagesPipeline', 'my.other.cool.s3.pipeline', ... ]

Comment: I think you didn't get me, I meant if I used my custom images pipeline, will it overwrite scrapy's core images pipeline ?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: But on the other side, I'm getting the warning message you added in the pipeline. So, now I'm getting both the warning and exception too. I want to get rid of this exception

Comment: paste all your code somewhere including your output and settings file

Comment: I'm sorry, to reply that late, but I was busy launching my project, what should I send you?

Comment: @Mahmoud: the more the merrier